# Is there any way to optimize this query?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I need to optimize the following query:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#TAB001') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE #TAB001;  

select *  
into #TAB001
from dbo.uvw_TAB001   
where 1 = 1  
and isnull(COD_CUSTOMER,'') = isnull(@cod_customer,isnull(COD_CUSTOMER,''))  
and isnull(TAXCODE,'') = isnull(@taxcode, isnull(TAXCODE,''))   
and isnull(SURNAME,'') = isnull(@surname,isnull(SURNAME,''))   
and isnull(VATCODE,'') = isnull(@vatCode,isnull(VATCODE,''))
```

The goal is to improve the performance of this query.
It is currently quite fast but I would like to speed it up even more.

This query has the optional parameters for which it is necessary to make a query that regardless of whether all or 1 parameter is set, returns results in the shortest possible time.

Comment: Well then whatever you do don't use `ISNULL` just to save some typing, that's a good way to ensure no indexes can be used. See [this](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#coalesce) and the rest of the article for an overview of what *is* good to do.

Comment: You could add indexes to the underlying table. Adding indexes is usually done by a Database Administrator. It depends if COD_CUSTOMER, TAXCODE, SURNAME, VATCODE are selected columns or calculated columns from the underlying table in the view. You can verify by scripting-out the view. If they were selected, I would add 1 index for each column to the underlying table. SQL Server should handle the merge joining for those indexes, or at least choose what it thinks is the most optimal combination of indexes. You confirm if SQL Server uses indexes by looking at the estimated execution plan in SSMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is known as a ["catch-all"](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) or ["kitchen sink"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) query, which need a little helping hand sometimes.

Firstly, you need to get rid of those `ISNULL`s; they are making the query non-SARGable. Also, I would suggest getting rid of the `SELECT *` and limiting the query to the columns you *need*.

Then, finally, we can add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query; why is discussed in the articles I linked above. This gives you the following:

```sql
SELECT * --Replace with Column Names
INTO #TAB001 --Do you actually need to do this?
FROM dbo.uvw_TAB001
--Removed WHERE 1 = 1 as it's always true, thus pointless
WHERE (COD_CUSTOMER = @cod_customer OR @cod_customer IS NULL)
  AND (TAXCODE = @taxcode OR @taxcode IS NULL)
  AND (SURNAME = @surname OR @surname IS NULL)
  AND (VATCODE = @vatCode OR @vatCode IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Note I am *assuming* that when a variable (for example `@cod_customer`) has the value `NULL` you mean that the variable should be "ignored" and not matched against `NULL`.

If you actually want `{Column} = @{Variable}` including `NULL` then use SQL with the format below instead:

```sql
({Column} = @{Variable} OR ({Column} IS NULL AND @{Variable} IS NULL))
```

Comment: See also: https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Hello Larnu, thanks for you support.
Reading the documentation you inserted in the link ["catch-all"](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) , it says "on large tables, can result in really poor query performance.". Despite this, the cpu_time was reduced by -99.24% and the total_elapsed_time was lower by -98.17%.

Comment: *Can* doesn't mean *will*, @VirtualCom . Though the specific article from Gail on `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is in the second article from her [here](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/).